# Delphi - Create component at runtime

Tags: delphi

how i can create component at runtime without declare a name of it in the variables

like

```
  for i := 0 to x do
  lHTTP[i] := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
```

Is it possible to declare a variable at run time ?

Comment: If you don't store a reference to the component, how are you going to refer to it? What is the context here?

Comment: What's preventing you from using *exactly* the code you've provided here? It looks fine to me.

Comment: "declare a variable at runtime" is precisely what your code already does. But don't expect to reference it by its name in this manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way or another, your component will have to be declared.  It looks like you want to create an array of components, so you could declare the components as members of an array and then create them exactly as in your example.

```
var
  lHTTP: array of TIdHTTP;
```

and of course you would need to set the length of the array before creating your first component, e.g.

```
setlength(lHTTP, 10);
```

Comment: Or, better yet, use a generic list - `TObjectList<TIdHTTP>`.

Comment: It's impossible to say whether this is "Better" without a lot more information about the context.  Without that context all that can be said about a generic TObjectList vs an array is that it is a *different*, alternative approach.